# Extract equations from a pdf that is compiled using Latex

Tags: equations, pdf, extract

Is there a way to extract math equations and figures from a pdf file that was compiled using Latex.

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "extracting" a math expression. (If you're aiming to "extract", or recover, the original LaTeX code, the short answer is: No.)

Comment: I want to get the mathematical equations from the Pdf and copy them to word not as images . thank you

Comment: You're best bet is probably trying to copying and paste from the PDF. Apart from that there are some PDF scraping programs but PDF is really hard to scrape. If you want to get hold of the LaTeX source you have almost no chance, I think. Personally, I'd strongly recommend against using word for equations...

Comment: regarding figures you can open PDF with Adobe Illustrator, go to the appropriate page, ungroup its contents and select the figure .. then you can open a new file, paste the figure and save it as an image that can be imported in Word .. this can be done and with equations but you can get them as figures (this is not what you want but it is impossible to get the original LaTEX code)

Comment: @Andrew i tried copy paste a disaster! Please what do you suggest rather than using word for equations. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris Thank you so much for the hint. I didn't know about using adobe Illustrator to extract figures.

Comment: There is a software called mathpix that should be able do that

Comment: @ArTourter  I'll try it . Thank you so much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.